# Unable to replace an element within an ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive which can have a recursive tree structure using AngularJS where each node can have its own template in the transclude section.

Here is the JS:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.input = [{
    name: 'blueberry cheesecake',
    color: 'blue',
    children: [{
      name: 'blueberry cheesecake',
      color: 'blue'
    }, {
      name: 'rocky road',
      color: 'mostly brown'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'rocky road',
    color: 'mostly brown'
  }];
});
app.directive("auratree", function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      input: "="
    },
    template: function(element) {
      element.data("customListTemplate", element.find("item-template"));
      var c =
        '<script type="text/ng-template" id="auratree2">' +
        '<item-placeholder></item-placeholder>' +
        '        <div ng-if="item.children">' +
        '          <div ng-repeat="item in item.children" ng-include="' +
        "'" + 'auratree2' + "'" + '">' +
        '            <item-placeholder></item-placeholder></div>' +
        '        </div>' +
        '</script>' +
        '<div ng-repeat="item in input" ng-include = "' + "'" + 'auratree2' + "'" + '">' +
        '</div>';
      console.log(c);
      return c;
    },
    compile: function(tElement, tAttrs) {
      var template = tElement.data("customListTemplate");
      tElement.find("script").html(tElement.find("script").html().replace("<item-    placeholder></item-placeholder>", template.html()));
    }
  };

  function link(scope, element, attrs) {}
});
```

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Aura Tree</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
    <script src="auratree.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <pre>template 1:</pre>
    <auratree input="input"> <item-template>
    {{$index}} | {{item.name}}
    <hr>
    </item-template> </auratree>
</body>
</html>
```

This code

```
tElement.find("script")
   .html(tElement.find("script").html()
   .replace("<item-placeholder></item-placeholder>",template.html()));
```

is working in Chrome, but is not working in IE11.

The usual element.replaceWith is not working, so I tried to change the html... but was unsuccessful.

Please tell me the solution to overcome this problem.

here is [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/t1BacIEjXPgM5EE3Tahs?p=info):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach with `ng-template` works as you expect it. Even if you manage to replace the placeholder in the `ng-template`, if you had multiple `<auratree>` elements in the app, each with a different item template, then all would have the same (last compiled) template.

Using `ng-include` is a clever trick, but this problem is somewhat more complicated. Instead of relying on an `ng-include`d template, include the same directive at each level at `link`-time (which is what `ng-include` would do anyway), and make use of `transclude` for the `item-template`.

Because of some asymmetry between a root element (which only has an array of items), and each sub-tree (which has the values and `children`) I added another directive to represent each tree item:

The root directive only repeats each item and transcludes the `item-template`:

```
app.directive("tree", function(){
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    scope: {
      items: "="
    },
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-repeat="item in items">\
                <tree-item item="item"></tree-item>\
              </div>',
    link: function(scope){
      scope.$level = -1;
    }
  };
});
```

The `treeItem` directive transcludes the `item-template` from the parent, and repeats child items, if any:

```
app.directive("treeItem", function($compile){
  return {
    scope: {
      item: "="
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrls, transclude){
      scope.$index = scope.$parent.$index;
      scope.$level = scope.$parent.$level + 1;

      transclude(scope, function(clone){
        element.append(clone.contents());
        var repeater = angular.element('<div ng-repeat="child in item.children">');
        var subtree = angular.element('<tree-item item="child">');

        element.append(repeater.append(subtree));

        $compile(repeater)(scope, null, { parentBoundTranscludeFn: transclude });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The usage is:

```
<tree items="items">
  <item-template>
    {{$level}}.{{$index}} | {{item.v}}
  </item-template>
</tree>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/fYDcQawwdWjavESl4Aa6?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Better put that template inside angular `$templateCache` in run phase of angular & remove that template from directive

**Run Block**

```
 app.run(function($templateCache) {

     $templateCache.put('auratree2', '<item-placeholder></item-placeholder>' +
         '        <div ng-if="item.children">' +
         '          <div ng-repeat="item in item.children" ng-include="' +
         "'" + 'auratree2' + "'" + '">' +
         '            <item-placeholder></item-placeholder></div>' +
         '        </div>'
     );
 });
```

**Directive** (template function)

```
template: function(element){       
  element.data("customListTemplate", element.find("item-template"));
  var c= '<div ng-repeat="item in input" ng-include = "' + "'" +'auratree2' +  "'"+ '"></div>';
  return c;
},
```

Comment: Does not work..  BTW the template has been cached.. but I want to replace the contents of the placeholder using replaceWith like **tElement.find("item-placeholder").replaceWith(template.contents());**

Answer (score -1):

Your plunkr had JQuery, but your StackOverflow question doesn't, so I'll assume you are using JQuery (you might have to because of JQLite's limitations).

In your HTML file, modify the order of JQuery and Angular so that the former is listed first.

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Aura Tree</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.3" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Comment: I think I might have added the jQuery in plunker by mistake, I am not using jQuery...